# nilpotent of rank one

Tags: operator-theory

I don't understand why we can foud the nilpotent operator?

---

Let S, T ∈ B(X) be invertible operators, Assume that there exists x ∈ X such that $S^{-1}Tx$ and x are linearly independent. Then we can find a nilpotent R of rank one satisfying $Rx = −S^{-1}Tx$

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, say $u = -S^{-1}Tx$.  You know $u$ is a nonzero vector in the range of $R$,
and since the rank is $1$ this and its scalar multiples are the only ones.  So $R: v \mapsto \phi(v) u$ where $\phi$ is a nonzero bounded linear functional on $X$, with $\phi(x) = 1$ to make $R(x) = u$.  On the other hand, you want $R$ to be nilpotent so you'd better have $R(u) = 0$, i.e. $\phi(u) = 0$.  Use Hahn-Banach to prove the existence of
such a $\phi$ and you're done.

But I hope you're not too particular about that "find".  Hahn-Banach uses the Axiom of Choice, and there may not be a guarantee that you can actually **construct** such a $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much, mister Robert, no I'm not trying to construct the operator. can you tell me which version of the theorem?.

Comment: Extend a linear functional from the span of $x$ and $u$ to the whole space.